# Custom eav category not showing in data front

Tags: magento2, category, eav, front

I have added an attribute to my category. The attribute is working well on backend (it's showing and saving correctly), but I can't get it on the front.

Here's how i've added this (install):

```
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'add_to_franco',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'franco',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'sort_order' => 333,
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => 1,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'system' => false,
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''

        ]
    );
```

This is the data i'm getting :

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 16
    [attribute_set_id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 2
    [created_at] => 2018-06-21 11:00:46
    [updated_at] => 2020-05-11 12:18:35
    [path] => 1/2/16
    [position] => 2
    [level] => 2
    [children_count] => 16
    [store_id] => 1
    [adresse_fournisseur] => 
    [all_children] => 
    [available_sort_by] => 
    [children] => 
    [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
    [custom_design] => 
    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0
    [default_sort_by] => 
    [description] => 
    [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
    [filter_price_range] => 
    [image] => 
    [include_in_menu] => 1
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_anchor] => 1
    [landing_page] => 
    [meta_description] => 
    [meta_keywords] => 
    [meta_title] => 
    [name] => Mes outils de communication
    [page_layout] => 
    [path_in_store] => 
    [poids_recherche] => 
    [url_key] => mes-outils-de-communication
    [url_path] => mes-outils-de-communication
)
```

And this is how i get the data :

```
 $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
 $data = $cat->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your db eav_attribute table search your attrtibute and set user_defined = true

and than run following command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: That's it, thanks !